# PHP Get Order Status name by State code?

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order, order-status, order-state

I am working on an extension and i need an info how to get the status name by state code, is it possible ?

[image]

The picture is from the Admin's panel Order Statuses page.

How i can get the status name by state code, is it possible ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, because it is a 1:n association, there are multiple statuses per state.

You can, however, get a list of all statuses that are assigned to a state `$stateCode`, and their names, with:

```
$statuses = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_collection')
    ->addStateFilter($stateCode)
    ->toOptionHash();
```

`$statuses` then contains an array in the form `$statusCode => $statusName`

#### Update:

According to your comments, you will need this:

```
$status = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status')->loadDefaultByState($stateCode);
echo $status->getStoreLabel();
```

(outputs the name of the default status for state with code `$stateCode`)

Comment: But what if there is only one status by the state code ?

Comment: Then my code results in an array with one element and you can use that element.

Comment: But I would prefer this: `Mage::getModel('sales/order_state')->loadDefaultByState($staeCode)` - will return the default status. If there is only one status, it will return this as well. If there are more, it will not give you the first it finds but the default status.

Comment: When i do that i got result giving only `Array` and no name..

Comment: You cannot `echo` an array. PHP basics...

Comment: How can i get the first result then and `echo` it ?

Comment: Also i've got this error with the last code given by you. `Fatal error: Call to a member function loadDefaultByState() `

Comment: Typo in the comment. See updated answer.

Comment: Everything is okey! Thank you so much! God bless you!